# D3.js Drawing geojson incorrectly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, openstreetmap, geojson

I am trying to visualize russians regions. I got data from [here](http://global.mapit.mysociety.org), validate [here](http://geojson.io/) and all was well - [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ev9f.jpg).

But when I try to draw it, I receive only one big black rectangle.

```
var width = 700, height = 400;

var svg = d3.select(".graph").append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width) + " " + (height))
        .style("max-width", "700px")
        .style("margin", "10px auto");


d3.json("83.json", function (error, mapData) {
    var features = mapData.features;

    var path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoMercator());

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "region")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
});
```

Example - http://ustnv.ru/d3/index.html
Geojson file - http://ustnv.ru/d3/83.json

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is the winding order of the coordinates (see [this block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a7bdfeb041e850799a8d3dce4d8c50c8)). Most tools/utilities/libraries/validators don't really care about winding order because they treat geoJSON as containing Cartesian coordinates. Not so with D3 - D3 uses ellipsoidal math - benefits of this is include being able to cross the antimeridian easily and being able to select an inverted polygon.

The consequence of using ellipsoidal coordinates is the wrong winding order will create a feature of everything on the planet that is not your target (inverted polygon). Your polygons actually contain a combination of both winding orders. You can see this by inspecting the svg paths:

[image]

Here one path appears to be accurately drawn, while another path on top of it covers the entire planet - except for the portion it is supposed to (the space it is supposed to occupy covered by other paths that cover the whole world).

This can be simple to fix - you just need to reorder the coordinates - but as you have features that contain both windings in the same collection, it'll be easier to use a library such as [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/docs#rewind) to create a new array of properly wound features:

```
    var fixed = features.map(function(feature) {
        return turf.rewind(feature,{reverse:true});
    })
```

Note the reverse winding order - through an odd quirk, D3, which is probably the most widespread platform where winding order matters actually doesn't follow the geoJSON spec (RFC 7946) on winding order, it uses the opposite winding order, see this comment by Mike Bostock:

> I’m disappointed that RFC 7946 standardizes the opposite winding order
>   to D3, Shapefiles and PostGIS. And I don’t see an easy way for D3 to
>   change its behavior, since it would break all existing (spherical)
>   GeoJSON used by D3. ([source](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/pull/79#issuecomment-280935242))

By rewinding each polygon we get a slightly more useful map:

[image]

An improvement, but the features are a bit small with these projection settings.

By adding a fitSize method to scale and translate we get a much better looking map (see [block here](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/7c1137fd4d3d6d6c6ff60d8558a0b6c5)):

[image]

Comment: OP's result without the winding, which is almost an ant on the screen, reminded me the map in step 2 of this [Bostock's tutorial](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/), where he says *"Lesser cartographers would now proclaim a job well-done and go home for a beer"*... oh, I cracked up!

Comment: I remember that line, appreciate his sense of humor - also remember working my way through that tutorial as my initial foray into d3. But, once you have the data and you can display it in some form, it is a good time to have a beer, often that's half the battle.

Comment: In my case, when I do the `d3.select("body").append("svg")` it's already the time for a break and a beer...

Comment: After 10h of hair pulling I found this gem, thanks!

Comment: you can rewind your geojson from here: https://davidb.dev/tools/rewind-geojson-online

Answer (score -2):

Here's a quick fix to your problem, projection needs a little tuning, also path has `fill:#000` by default and `stroke: #FFF` could make it more legible.

```
var width = 700, height = 400;

var svg = d3.select(".graph").append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width) + " " + (height))
        .style("max-width", "700px")
        .style("margin", "10px auto");


d3.json("mercator_files/83.json", function (error, mapData) {
    var features = mapData.features;


    var center = d3.geoCentroid(mapData);
    //arbitrary
    var scale  = 7000;
    var offset = [width/2, height/2];
    var projection = d3.geoMercator().scale(scale).center(center)
      .translate(offset);

     var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "region")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
});
```

Comment: While path style and projection require tweaking, I don't see how this addresses the core issue: features are inverted and thus cover the entire map plane. Using your code I find [this](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/a885d35b628671b81b45ff6949000dbe) , not all features are visible (all are drawn) and paths still exceed the bounds of the svg (which is why `fitSize()`/`fitExtent()` won't work with these features, this could also cause wonky behavior with `d3.geoCentroid()`)