# D3.js svg does not draw Map

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to draw maps using D3.js. The GeoJson file is converted from shapefile and  stored in the project folder.

The GeoJson data format:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[31.287890625000017,-22.40205078125001],[31.429492187500017,-22.298828125],[31.57148437500001,-22.15351562500001],[31.737695312500023,-21.9833984375],[31.88593750000001,-21.83154296875],[32.01630859375001,-21.698046875000003],[32.19472656250002,-21.515429687500003],[32.37109375,-21.33486328125001],[32.41240234375002,-21.311816406250003],[32.429785156250006,-21.29707031250001],[32.353613281250006,-21.136523437500003],[32.476171875000006,-20.95009765625001],[32.48281250000002,-20.828906250000003],[32.477636718750006,-20.712988281250006],[32.49238281250001,-20.659765625000006],[32.529296875,-20.613085937500003],[32.67255859375001,-20.51611328125],[32.780859375000006,-20.36152343750001],[32.86962890625,-20.21718750000001],[32.992773437500006,-19.98486328125],[33.0048828125,-19.93017578125],[33.00673828125002,-19.873828125000003],[32.97265625,-19.79541015625],[32.89042968750002,-19.668066406250006],[32.83076171875001,-19.558203125000006],[32.77763671875002,-19.388769531250006],[32.83095703125002,-19.24140625000001],[32.85000000000002,-19.152441406250006],[32.84980468750001,-19.10439453125001],[32.826171875,-19.05878906250001],[32.766210937500006,-19.02431640625001],[32.71650390625001,-19.00185546875001],[32.69970703125,-18.94091796875],[32.69921875,-18.868457031250003],[32.72197265625002,-18.828417968750003],[32.8544921875,-18.763671875],[32.88457031250002,-18.728515625],[32.90029296875002,-18.689062500000006],[32.90166015625002,-18.632910156250006],[32.942480468750006,-18.49267578125],[32.99306640625002,-18.35957031250001],[32.99638671875002,-18.312597656250006],[32.978515625,-18.271484375],[32.96464843750002,-18.1962890625],[32.95556640625,-18.08291015625001],[32.954687500000006,-17.765429687500003],[32.98076171875002,-17.4375],[32.969335937500006,-17.251562500000006],[32.884375000000006,-17.03779296875001],[32.87626953125002,-16.883593750000003],[32.93789062500002,-16.775976562500006],[32.94804687500002,-16.71230468750001],[32.902929687500006,-16.704199218750006],[32.81025390625001,-16.69765625000001],[32.741796875000006,-16.67763671875001],[32.635839843750006,-16.589453125000006],[32.45195312500002,-16.515722656250006],[32.243261718750006,-16.44873046875],[31.939843750000023,-16.428808593750006],[31.687597656250006,-16.214160156250003],[31.489843750000006,-16.1796875],[31.426171875000023,-16.15234375],[31.236230468750023,-16.02363281250001],[30.938769531250017,-16.01171875],[30.630175781250017,-15.999218750000011],[30.437792968750017,-15.995312500000011],[30.40937500000001,-15.978222656250011],[30.39814453125001,-15.80078125],[30.396093750000006,-15.64306640625],[30.25068359375001,-15.643457031250009],[29.994921875000017,-15.64404296875],[29.729589843750006,-15.644628906250006],[29.4873046875,-15.69677734375],[29.287890625000017,-15.776464843750006],[29.050585937500017,-15.901171875000003],[28.973046875000023,-15.950097656250009],[28.9130859375,-15.98779296875],[28.875585937500006,-16.0361328125],[28.856738281250017,-16.14228515625001],[28.856738281250017,-16.30615234375],[28.83271484375001,-16.424121093750003],[28.760546875000017,-16.53212890625001],[28.760644531250023,-16.53193359375001],[28.399804687500023,-16.66279296875001],[28.16376953125001,-16.76972656250001],[27.932226562500006,-16.89619140625001],[27.75654296875001,-17.060351562500003],[27.63671875,-17.26210937500001],[27.437890625000023,-17.51191406250001],[27.235742187500023,-17.728320312500003],[27.020800781250017,-17.95839843750001],[26.779882812500006,-18.04150390625],[26.577539062500023,-18.022558593750006],[26.333398437500023,-17.929296875000006],[26.139550781250023,-17.911718750000006],[25.995898437500017,-17.969824218750006],[25.86328125,-17.951953125000003],[25.741601562500023,-17.858203125000003],[25.6396484375,-17.82412109375001],[25.55712890625,-17.84951171875001],[25.451757812500006,-17.84511718750001],[25.2587890625,-17.793554687500006],[25.239062500000017,-17.843066406250003],[25.224023437500023,-17.91523437500001],[25.242285156250006,-17.969042968750003],[25.28242187500001,-18.04121093750001],[25.340234375000023,-18.1044921875],[25.384375000000006,-18.14199218750001],[25.43671875000001,-18.234960937500006],[25.4892578125,-18.35126953125001],[25.55830078125001,-18.44179687500001],[25.76123046875,-18.649218750000003],[25.78369140625,-18.72353515625001],[25.811914062500023,-18.79707031250001],[25.939355468750023,-18.93867187500001],[25.95917968750001,-18.985644531250003],[25.95068359375,-19.08173828125001],[26.081933593750023,-19.369921875000003],[26.168066406250006,-19.53828125000001],[26.241015625000017,-19.5693359375],[26.474609375,-19.748632812500006],[26.67822265625,-19.89277343750001],[26.91669921875001,-19.99013671875001],[27.091796875,-20.05419921875],[27.17822265625,-20.10097656250001],[27.221484375000017,-20.145800781250003],[27.256738281250023,-20.232031250000006],[27.27460937500001,-20.3818359375],[27.28076171875,-20.47871093750001],[27.46894531250001,-20.47480468750001],[27.624609375000006,-20.48359375000001],[27.679296875000006,-20.503027343750006],[27.699609375000023,-20.53066406250001],[27.69482421875,-20.594531250000003],[27.69697265625001,-20.689746093750003],[27.70429687500001,-20.766406250000003],[27.688085937500006,-20.84833984375001],[27.67695312500001,-20.94482421875],[27.66943359375,-21.064257812500003],[27.693457031250006,-21.11103515625001],[27.844140625000023,-21.261523437500003],[27.90742187500001,-21.35908203125001],[27.974609375,-21.50673828125001],[28.014062500000023,-21.55419921875],[28.04560546875001,-21.573046875000003],[28.181640625,-21.58935546875],[28.532031250000017,-21.65126953125001],[28.74775390625001,-21.707617187500006],[28.919335937500023,-21.76601562500001],[28.99072265625,-21.78144531250001],[29.02558593750001,-21.796875],[29.03730468750001,-21.811328125000003],[29.01582031250001,-21.93994140625],[29.023339843750023,-21.981250000000003],[29.042382812500023,-22.018359375000003],[29.07148437500001,-22.047460937500006],[29.106835937500023,-22.065722656250003],[29.237207031250023,-22.07949218750001],[29.315234375000017,-22.15771484375],[29.364843750000006,-22.193945312500006],[29.37744140625,-22.19277343750001],[29.6630859375,-22.146289062500003],[29.90234375,-22.184179687500006],[30.1904296875,-22.291113281250006],[30.46015625000001,-22.32900390625001],[30.71162109375001,-22.2978515625],[30.916113281250006,-22.29072265625001],[31.07343750000001,-22.30781250000001],[31.197265625,-22.34492187500001],[31.287890625000017,-22.40205078125001]]]},"properties":{"featurecla":"Admin-0 country","scalerank":1,"LABELRANK":3,"SOVEREIGNT":"Zimbabwe","SOV_A3":"ZWE","ADM0_DIF":0,"LEVEL":2,"TYPE":"Sovereign country","ADMIN":"Zimbabwe","ADM0_A3":"ZWE","GEOU_DIF":0,"GEOUNIT":"Zimbabwe","GU_A3":"ZWE","SU_DIF":0,"SUBUNIT":"Zimbabwe","SU_A3":"ZWE","BRK_DIFF":0,"NAME":"Zimbabwe","NAME_LONG":"Zimbabwe","BRK_A3":"ZWE","BRK_NAME":"Zimbabwe","BRK_GROUP":"","ABBREV":"Zimb.","POSTAL":"ZW","FORMAL_EN":"Republic of Zimbabwe","FORMAL_FR":"","NAME_CIAWF":"Zimbabwe","NOTE_ADM0":"","NOTE_BRK":"","NAME_SORT":"Zimbabwe","NAME_ALT":"","MAPCOLOR7":1,"MAPCOLOR8":5,"MAPCOLOR9":3,"MAPCOLOR13":9,"POP_EST":13805084,"POP_RANK":14,"GDP_MD_EST":28330,"POP_YEAR":2017,"LASTCENSUS":2002,"GDP_YEAR":2016,"ECONOMY":"5. Emerging region: G20","INCOME_GRP":"5. Low income","WIKIPEDIA":-99,"FIPS_10_":"ZI","ISO_A2":"ZW","ISO_A3":"ZWE","ISO_A3_EH":"ZWE","ISO_N3":"716","UN_A3":"716","WB_A2":"ZW","WB_A3":"ZWE","WOE_ID":23425004,"WOE_ID_EH":23425004,"WOE_NOTE":"Exact WOE match as country","ADM0_A3_IS":"ZWE","ADM0_A3_US":"ZWE","ADM0_A3_UN":-99,"ADM0_A3_WB":-99,"CONTINENT":"Africa","REGION_UN":"Africa","SUBREGION":"Eastern Africa","REGION_WB":"Sub-Saharan Africa","NAME_LEN":8,"LONG_LEN":8,"ABBREV_LEN":5,"TINY":-99,"HOMEPART":1,"MIN_ZOOM":0,"MIN_LABEL":3,"MAX_LABEL":8,"NE_ID":1159321441,"WIKIDATAID":"Q954","NAME_AR":"زيمبابوي","NAME_BN":"জিম্বাবুয়ে","NAME_DE":"Simbabwe","NAME_EN":"Zimbabwe","NAME_ES":"Zimbabue","NAME_FR":"Zimbabwe","NAME_EL":"Ζιμπάμπουε","NAME_HI":"ज़िम्बाब्वे","NAME_HU":"Zimbabwe","NAME_ID":"Zimbabwe","NAME_IT":"Zimbabwe","NAME_JA":"ジンバブエ","NAME_KO":"짐바브웨","NAME_NL":"Zimbabwe","NAME_PL":"Zimbabwe","NAME_PT":"Zimbábue","NAME_RU":"Зимбабве","NAME_SV":"Zimbabwe","NAME_TR":"Zimbabve","NAME_VI":"Zimbabwe","NAME_ZH":"辛巴威"}},
```

My code:

```
<svg id="mapSVG" width="560"; height="350" style="border: solid 1px black;"></svg>
<script src="js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Setting svg width and attributes
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var width = +svg.attr("width");
var height = +svg.attr("height");

d3.json("Resources/countries.json").then(function (json) {
    var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], json);

    //Projections
    var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
     svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
         .attr("d", geoPath)
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
    
})
```

Problems: The SVG is completely empty. There is no error log in the console and I tried to output the json and it is actually getting the data.

When I inspect the svg, the size of the whole svg is `560x350`, so I tried to play with the `translate` and `center`, but had no luck with it.

Comment: `center` takes coordinates representing longitude, latitude, not pixels (`translate` moves the map based on pixels, `center` on lat/long). You've provided an invalid centering coordinate (100E,200N). Try removing that line or using better centering coordinates. I see the one feature you've shared when doing so; however, you have a winding order issue (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311635/7106086)) and you may want to better (automatically) center features (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940028/7106086))

Comment: I have changed it to use automatic feature, but now it looks like a thick vertical strip across the SVG with both sides being white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AndrewReid was correct. It was a winding problem and fortunately there is a simple way to fix it using `turf.js`

```
d3.json(path).then(function (json) {
        var projection = d3.geoMercator();
        var features = json.features;

        var fixed = features.map(function (feature) {
            return turf.rewind(feature, { reverse: true });
        })
        //Projections
        var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

        projection.fitSize([width, height], { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": fixed })

        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(fixed)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", geoPath)
```