# Why is the 'fill' attribute colouring the entire svg area instead of only the path?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a map projection using d3.js which works fine at first with "fill" set to "none".

d3.js projection without fill:

[image: d3.js projection without fill]

However, when I try and the path "fill" attribute to a colour it creates areas which fill the entire svg and overlap other paths.

ds.js projection with fill:

[image: ds.js projection with fill]

The code for the project is below. I thought that maybe the paths are not closed but I can't seem to work out what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Map of Wales</title>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      let width = 600,
        height = 600;

      d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .style("width", width)
        .style("height", height);

      let projection = d3
        .geoMercator()
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
        .center([-3.7, 52.4])
        .scale([width / 0.06]);

      let geoGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

      d3.json("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/50d3f1363f144a94bde9353520697207_0.geojson").then((wales) => {
        d3.select("svg")
          .append("g")
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(wales.features)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("d", geoGenerator)
          .attr("stroke", "#000000")
          .attr("fill", "blue")
          .attr("fill-opacity", 0.2)
          .attr("id", (d) => d.properties.nawc18cd)
          .attr("class", "constituency");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Most likely a [winding order problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311001/7106086)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by rewinding the geojson data as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311001/d3-js-drawing-geojson-incorrectly).