# How to get D3 to plot all elements of a GeoJson file?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geojson

**Goal**

- Plot school districts from WA state in D3 v5.

**Steps taken**

1. Download shape file from [link](https://ofm.wa.gov/washington-data-research/population-demographics/gis-data/census-geographic-files) (Using "Census 2020" -> "School districts (county parts)")
2. Import shape file into [mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/)

   - Selected "detect line intersections" & "snap vertices" (if I don’t click the second option it warns me that there are "2920 line intersections").
     [Image of file projected within mapshaper.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC67n.jpg)
3. Unproject the data within mapshaper by using the command "-proj wgs84" in the console.
   [Image of file unprojected within mapshaper.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxNmW.jpg)
4. Export the file as GeoJSON
5. Attempt to plot within D3 using the code listed below. The result is just one school district as shown
   [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqVXg.jpg)

   - I believe I have set an appropriate projection/path since I try to plot the state of Washington using another GeoJSON file the shape appears appropriately.
   - When I inspect “Elements” the svg object has multiple paths but only one appears to be plotting. [example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtNcY.jpg)
   - I believe the GeoJSON file is valid as it works within mapshaper and I also validated it within https://geojson.io.

**Code**

```
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg");

d3.json("unsd20p.json").then(function(geojson) {
  var outline_projection = d3.geoMercator()
                             .center([-120.740135,47.751076])
                             .scale(5000)

  var outline_path = d3.geoPath()
                       .projection(outline_projection);

  svg.selectAll('path')
     .data(geojson.features)
     .enter()
     .append('path')
     .attr('d' , outline_path)
     .style('stroke', 'black')
     .style('fill', 'white')
});
</script>
```

**Data**

Here's [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NsTLXeEtPlr9kqs0IF6juDJJTkoNh4wC/view?usp=sharing) to exact data set I am using. Also included steps to get this exact dataset above.

I really appreciate any help you all can provide in getting this resolved! I am new to stackoverflow so it is not letting me embed photos; however, the links should work. I've reviewed several tutorials before posting and none seemed to resolve this.

Comment: Likely a winding order issue - you could set the fill to `none`  and see if everything *appears* normally drawn with just the stroke. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311635/7106086).

Comment: That solved it! Thanks so much.