# Plot geojson with d3js, fill map

Tags: d3.js

I exported the following query from [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1etH):

```
[out:json];
area["name"="Berlin"]->.berlinArea;
rel(area.berlinArea)["admin_level"~"9|4"][boundary=administrative];
out geom;
area["name"="Großbeeren"]->.beerenArea;
rel(area.beerenArea)["admin_level"~"9|4"][boundary=administrative];
out geom;
```

And try to visualize the result with d3js. For the first trail I followed this [tutorial](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/backgroundmap_country.html) and only edit the attributes scale and center as you can see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
        
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
        
<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<svg id="my_dataviz" width="800" height="800"></svg>

<script>
// The svg
const svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

// Map and projection
const projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .center([13.53, 52.41])                // GPS of location to zoom on
    .scale(30000)                       // This is like the zoom
    .translate([ width/2, height/2 ])

// Load external data and boot
d3.json("file:///D:/temp/test.geojson").then( function(data){

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .join("path")
          .attr("fill", "grey")
          .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
              .projection(projection)
          )
        .style("stroke", "black")
})
</script>
```

But in the result plot there are some polygons left as you can see in the screenshot. But the dataset contains the unplotted polygons, I guess.
[image]

If I change the fill attribute to "none" all ploygons are visible:
[image]

Comment: This is a winding order issue - the polygons are inverted, which is why you only see one when applying a fill: each polygon covers the entire world except for the area it is intended to cover. As D3 uses spherical geometry (unlike really any other geojson utility which use Cartesian coordinates), winding order matters. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311001/7106086).

Comment: Thx for correction. I marked this question as duplicate.