# geo.json d3 projection no valid path is generated

Tags: d3.js, geojson

i have a problem with the geo.json from [source](https://github.com/ginseng666/GeoJSON-TopoJSON-Austria/blob/master/2021/simplified-99.9/bezirke_999_geo.json).
In the Github preview it looks fine, but not in my app. One of the other geo files from there is working fine on my app. (laender_999_geo.json)

Usually im am using `projection.fitSize` for country specific data geo files, but here the path is totaly wrong. On [codepen](https://codepen.io/spliomix/pen/jOaxPOX) you can see the behavior. (maybe you have to disable cors)
It displays with `geoMercator()` a rectangle with a very small undefiend path [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aif4i.png), on zooming [zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOYbF.png) in this could be a few right paths, but the most others are missing.
I tried different projections and scales, but i dont get the right result.

So what can i do to generate the right view of the districts and villages?

To preserve the code:

```
const render = (village) => {
  const geoMap = d3.select("#geo-map").append("g").attr("id", "village");

  const projection = d3.geoMercator();

  projection.fitSize([500, 500], village);
  geoMap
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(village.features)
    .join("path")
    .attr("d", d3.geoPath().projection(projection))
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("fill", (d) => "blue")
    .attr("id", (d) => {
      return d.properties.name;
    });
};

/*
works:
d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ginseng666/GeoJSON-TopoJSON- 
Austria/master/2021/simplified-99.9/laender_999_geo.json')*/

d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ginseng666/GeoJSON-TopoJSON-Austria/master/2021/simplified-99.9/bezirke_999_geo.json"
).then(function (json) {
  render(json);
});
```

Comment: At a glance, looks like a [winding order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311635/7106086) issue.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had never found this. It works with the usage of turf.rewind() from you link.