# D3.js geo-projection projects the entire Earth

Tags: d3.js

I have just used D3.js geo-projection to create a country map. However, the projection seems to project the country and the **entire earth**. From the image below, we can see a clear boundary, which indicates (-180, -90) -> (180, 90) (latitude and longitude).
[image]
[image]
I just wrote the simplest code for the d3.js map:

```
const projection = d3.geoEquirectangular();
projection.fitSize([width, height], data);
const path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
```

I am sure my .geojson file only contains the multi polygon w.r.t a single country. The points do not exceed the country, i.e., I do not have a point at (180, 90).

I don't know why d3.js added the entire earth boundary for me. I just want the single country to fit the SVG size.

I use the same code for a province, which correctly fits the SVG without a boundary. See the image below.
[image]

Comment: You have an improperly wound feature. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311001/7106086)

Answer (score 1):

`fitSize` (and the related `fitExtent`) map the projection into *output* space, i.e., a rectangle on the screen. In your example, you have fit the rendering of the projection into a box (say, a `<div>` or an `<svg>`) with dimensions `[width, height]`, but have not actually modified the projection. To do that, you probably want something like `projection.center([lat, lon]).scale(scale)`.